# Nonuniform scaling during point registration

Tags: python, shapely

I am using shapely and would like to register between 2D rectangles. Specifically, I would like to find the match between "L"s of triangles (three consecutive points mapped to three consecutive points of another triangle).

I wanted to use shapely's `affine_matrix_from_points` but the documentation states:

> The returned matrix performs rotation, translation and uniform scaling (if specified).

Why does it only perform uniform scaling? (Lets say I map a 2 by 3 triangle to a 12 by 12 triangle, I would like scaleX=6, scaleY=4 etc).

Is this an algebraic limitation or an implementation issue?

Comment: In Euclidean geometry, an affine transformation, or an affinity (from the Latin, affinis, "connected with"), is a geometric transformation that preserves lines and parallelism (but not necessarily distances and angles). (...) Examples of affine transformations include translation, scaling, homothety, similarity, reflection, rotation, shear mapping, and compositions of them in any combination and sequence. 
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: Where is shapely's `affine_matrix_from_points` ?